# JHipster app does not work under prod mode

Tags: angular5, jhipster, yarnpkg

I have a monolith application that under dev mode everything works ok. When I package the application for production the front-end does not work.
The back end runs ok.
Do you have any suggestions/advices how to debug this?
I have cleaned and reinstalled the node_modules and the yarn.lock file. 
No difference.
Any advice would be really appreciated.

```
Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules Executing jhipster:info Options:  Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

##### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**


<details> <summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary> <pre> {   "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "---"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.14.0",
    "baseName": "devkit",
    "packageName": "---",
    "packageFolder": "---",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mssql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mssql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "replaced-by-jhipster-info",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false   } } </pre> </details>




##### **Environment and Tools**

java version "1.8.0_161" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_161-b12) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

git version 2.15.0.windows.1

node: v8.9.4

npm: 5.6.0

yeoman: 2.0.1

yarn: 1.3.2

Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24

docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b2

Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you build it?

Comment: Probably not related but the error about favicon.icon shows that `${baseUrl}` is not expanded, so probably something is wrong in your prod application properties

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. While I was trying to debug I found the SERVER_API_URL under the webpack.common.js. I set this to a URL where the I launched the API. After that I have used the http-server from nodeJs to serve the front end. And it works. But I haven't found the original problem. What you say must be correct. The properties are basically the same (dev & prod). The angular program does not startup correctly that is why we see these messages.

Comment: The problem is related when the frontend id being served from tomcat that serves the backend as well.

Comment: This is an important point. So you don't use embedded undertow but deploy within tomcat? I'm sorry I can't be of any help here.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou you misunderstood me.
I use the default settings that come with JHipster:
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

Comment: I found the cause of the issue. I wanted to have the packaging as a jar and not war so I changed the pom packaging to jar.
This was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to produce a jar instead of a war archive broke the application under prod mode. Changing the filename of the archive that will be produced is easy by simply including the `<fileName>` tag under the build tag but if you want to change the extensions then do not change the `<packaging>` tag since this will break the app under production.

UPDATE:
I found that simply renaming the file from war to jar by hand (manually) breaks the front end with the previous described error.